# Symfony problem with fixtures when running phpunit with sqlite

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am trying to configure symfony to use sqlite for tests.

composer.json (require-dev)

```
"doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.1",
"liip/functional-test-bundle": "~2.0@alpha",
```

config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    driver: 'pdo_sqlite'
    url: 'sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/test.db3'
```

then I made a test like this

```
class SimplestTest extends WebTestCase
{

private $fixtures;

public function setUp()
{
    $this->fixtures = $this->loadFixtures([
        MyFixtures::class
        ])->getReferenceRepository();
}

public function testToSeeIfItWorks()
{
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
}
```

MyFixtures class extends AbstractFixture and load some simple objects:

```
class MyFixtures extends AbstractFixture
{
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{

    $user1 = new User();
    $user1->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);

    $manager->persist($user1);
    $manager->flush();

    $myFeed = new Feed();
    $myFeed->setName('Feed 1');
    $myFeed->setUrl('http://someurl');
    $myFeed->setUser($user1);

    $manager->persist($myFeed);
    $manager->flush();
}
}
```

When I run the test I get:

```
InvalidArgumentException: "App\Tests\DataFixtures\ORM\MyFixtures" is not a registered fixture
```

no idea why. any help?

thank you

Comment: Can you paste the code for MyFixtures?

Comment: @Emma tried already same thing

Comment: @MichałTomczuk I updated the question with the fixture code.

Comment: Check AbstractTest class [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/80bu/rolling-back-doctrine-data-fixture-changes-with-phpunit-tests-in-symfony-applications) that registers fixtures.

Comment: @user3174311 your whole code looks like it should work. There is one thing I would change - you are flushing twice in `MyFixture`, remove the first `$manager->flush()`. Maybe, for whatever dark doctrine reason, it produces the error.

Comment: @MichałTomczuk same thing, actually I added it in an attempt to solve.

Comment: And if you just add the user and comment out the feed part on the fixture, will it work?

Comment: @MichałTomczuk nope. I actually also tried with an empty load() method, same thing.

Comment: Which version of `liip/functional-test-bundle` are you using? If it is the latest 2.0 alpha (so `alhpa15` at the moment), then you should change your database config like [shown here](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle/blob/2.0.0-alpha15/doc/database.md#sqlite), so use `path` parameter and nullify the `url` parameter - maybe that helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I know what's the problem. There seems to be a bug in library's documentation if it comes to the class the fixture should extend from. In [the documentation](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle/blob/2.0.0-alpha15/doc/database.md#referencing-fixtures-in-tests) in states to use `Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture`, but it makes the fixture not load automatically.

As you can read in DoctrineFixturesBundle [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#loading-fixtures), the bundle will add a `doctrine.fixture.orm` tag by autowiring to any class that implements `ORMFixtureInterface`, like `Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture`. Loading fixtures from classes that implement the interface is done by `FixturesCompilerPass`.

If you change the base class of your fixture to `Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture` it should work.

**Update:**

On top of all above the fixture class has to be located in `App\DataFixtures` namespace.

That is because that namespace is configured to be autowired and autoconfigured. If you want to keep your fixture files under `App\Tests\DataFixtures\`, add proper configuration to `config/services.yaml` file:

```
services:
    App\Tests\DataFixtures\:
        resource: '../tests/DataFixtures'
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. BTW, I have another fixtures class that extends Fixtures with data I use for development and it works when I run doctrine:fixtures:load. But this one is used by the test kernel from phpunit, so I think this is a configuration problem related to sqlite. Also if I change config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml to use mysql it works.

Comment: Ok, try moving the fixture from `src/Tests/DataFixtures/ORM` to `src/DataFixtures`. When I moved my fixture from the `src/DataFixtures` to the directory structured like yours, I got the error about fixture not being registered - maybe that's another requirement for the fixtures to autoload? Be sure to make it extend `Fixture`, like in the answer.

Comment: great! this actually do the trick. now I am going to see if everything else is working as expected, like creating the client for my functional test, but the error is gone. I think you should amend the answer to include this bit in case someone else will need it in the future. thank you so much.